# How to link from drawer Item to external website react-native-expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have here this drawer

```
 return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="MetalDetector" screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#8e9dad',
          width: 220
        }
      }}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="MetalDetector" component={Home} options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Entypo name="sound" size={24} color="black" /> 
          ),
          drawerLabel: ' MetalDetector'
        }}  />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{drawerLabel: ' Settings'}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Calibrate" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: ' Calibration'}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Feedback" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: '‍‍‍ Feedback'}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Website" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: ' Website'}} />
        
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I have added a few drawerScreens, like settings calibration feedback and website, but how can i make it that when someone clicks on website that he gets actually redirected to a website?

Currently I have

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Website" component={Home} options={{drawerLabel: ' Website'}} />
```

I tried to add an onclick and onPress function but when removing the component I get an error and with using the component I cant link to anywhere

How can i fix this?

Comment: which version of react-navigation you are using?

Comment: "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",

Comment: so that was your whole help, asking me what version i Use?

Comment: Please check the API document for react-navigation drawer v6 for changing default events.

Comment: If this is your attitude to ask people for help, please never ask again. The offical document in react-navigation v6 had written how to replace the default event for drawer items. Please do more research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [drawerContent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent) prop. Check out this [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pavankommi/b311b9) to see how it's done.